# IOUtils.copy() hangs when copying big stream?

Tags: java, stream, apache-commons-io

I want to parse content of some file by [srcML](http://www.sdml.info/projects/srcml/) parser which is an external windows program. I'm doing this in a following way:

```
String command = "src2srcml.exe --language java";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

InputStream fileInput = Files.newInputStream(file)
OutputStream procOutput = proc.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(fileInput, procOutput);
```

IOUtils.copy() is from Commons IO 2.4 library.

When my file is small (several KB) everything works fine. However, when I try to copy some relatively big file (~72 KB) my program hangs.

Moreover, when I execute the parser 'manually' in cmd:

```
src2srcml.exe --language Java < BigFile.java
```

everything works fine, too.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the size and not the stream itself? There is a method IOUtils.copyLarge(in, out), but is for streams bigger than 2GB. So 72 KB should not be a problem.

Comment: @luanjot You're probably right. But then, what could be the problem? Characters encoding?

Comment: I can't help you there because I don't know how src2srcml works. What is the output? Text? Can you print it in any way to the console?

Comment: does the external program generate output on standard out?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, it does

Comment: If you want to copy a file to an OutputStream, and you're making use of the Files class anyway, why not use `Files.copy(file, procOutput);`?

Comment: @VGR Because, in fact, I need to replace several characters in file using ReplaceInputStream. I presented a simplified example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should buffer the OutputStream:

```
OutputStream procOutput = proc.getOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(procOutput);
IOUtils.copy(fileInput, bos);
```

Moreover, why don't you simply redirect fileInput as the process InputStream?

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 pb.redirectInput(file);
 Process proc = pb.start();
 proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks, using BufferedOutputStream worked. I cannot simply redirect input, because, in fact, my input stream is a ReplaceInputStream (I need to replace several characters before parsing).

Comment: @Kao - using BufferedOutputStream is only a partial solution.  it will fail again when your input gets large enoough.  see my answer.

Comment: @jtahlborn But the Java program  is piping to the external program, so this should not require another thread in the Java program. (Other way round: absolutely!)

Comment: @laune I would like to use ProcessBuilder as you mentioned in second part of your answer. But, is there any way to redirect input to Stream? `pb.redirectInput()` accepts only File or ProcessBuilder.Redirect, which can be created only from File.

Comment: @Kao In this case, use Process.getOutputStream(), wrap into a BuffredOutputStream and write to it.

Comment: @laune - the code isn't shown here, but presumably the java program is consuming the output of the external program.  in this case, the java program must use two threads, one to write to the program and one to read from the program.

Comment: @jtahlborn If it isn't shown here: who are we to invent or even discuss it ;-))

Comment: @laune - um, because it's pertinent to the solution?

Comment: @jtahlborn yes, the program is consuming the output

Comment: @Kao - as i said in my answer, you _must_ use two threads.  the BufferedOOutputStream only bought you a little more file size before you will block again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that you are not consuming the output of the external program in a separate thread.  you need to start a separate thread to consume the output so that the external program does not get blocked.